# Jsoup when using .children().get(22) OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception, jsoup

I want to select 42 item from a menu, when i pass 22 the 42 element are printed but it show me a outofboundsException. Help me out.

```
Elements links3 = doc.select("menu#zz18_ViewSelectorMenu");
        for (Element link : links3) {
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.children().get(22).attr("onMenuClick"));
        }
```

I have this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5150
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 22, size is 22 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:544)
at com.example.projet1.wsActivity$1.run(wsActivity.java:117)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use get(21) if you want last element

the arraylist size is 22( arralylist indexes starts from 0)

```
 for (Element link : links3) {
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.children().get(21).attr("onMenuClick"));
        }
```

and it is good practicing of catching IndexOutofBounds Exceptions

it has only 22 elements

```
 Elements elements = doc.select("menu#EE18_ViewSelectorMenu");
                Elements menuelements =elements.get(0).children();
                for (int i = 0; i < menuelements.size(); i++) {
                    String required = menuelements.get(i)
                            .attr("onMenuClick");
                }
```

Comment: yha you where right my bad that worked out perfectly thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid index 22, size is 22

...is telling you that the size of the `ArrayList` is `22`, and so the max index you can use is `21`. Indexes in `List`s are 0-based, so if you have 22 items in the list, their indexes are `0` through `21`.

So just for completeness, with an `ArrayList` with size = 5:

- 0 - first entry
- 1 - second
- 2 - third
- 3 - fourth
- 4 - last